# How to get the results of multithreads into a ArrayList ? Because when I do I get concurrentException because still the threads are alive

Tags: java, arraylist, formatting

Need some help in figuring the multithreads created for URL's and get those URL where response time is greater than 500 and read those URL's to a arraylist.I tried to add those URL to arrylist but url's are not getting stored completely into the list because still there are few threads that in execution state

```
public class ArrayReadandThreadCreator extends Thread
{
public String s=null;
public static Thread t;
static  ArrayList<String> array1  = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayReadandThreadCreator(String s2)
{
this.s=s2;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
String s1 = "";
//Demo.array contains list of URL's
ListIterator<String> li = Demo.array.listIterator();
{
while(li.hasNext())
{
s1 = li.next();
ArrayReadandThreadCreator at1 = newArrayReadandThreadCreator(s1);
t  = new Thread(at1);
t.start();
}
}   
}
public void run()
{           
try
{           
URL url = new URL(s);
HttpURLConnection hs = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
long res = 500;
long systime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long delaytime = System.currentTimeMillis() - res;
if(delaytime>res)
{
String s5 = url.toString();
array1.add(s5);             
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with the question. Can you post the proper code?

Comment: `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(url.toString().split(somePattern)))` to ensure that is an arrayList

Comment: What 20 strings does `url.toString()` contain? Hint; it's one string.

Comment: if I use new ArrayList the result is like, the new array is getting created for every single String.
i.e array1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(url.toString().split("\n")));
output
------
[www.google.com]
[www.gmail.com]

I am using multi thread for every single URL , So if the delay time is > res time . I get multiple URL's in the section
if (delaytime > res) {
    System.out.println(url.toString()); // this will print 20 strings   these results are to be stored into arraylist
}           
now is there any possibility to add these URL's or Strings to a new ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just correct myself for the above program.
1) created multiple threads for a task in to array
2) you can't get the results in the array before all threads are ended
3) so used join(). And got the expected results

Answer (score 1):

```
...
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
if (delaytime > res) {
    result.add(url.toString()); // this will store 20 strings inside list  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
String[] splittedContent = url.toString().split("\n");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(splittedContent);
```

Comment: @nachokk This is a collaborative site. You could fix the error if you have found any. Thanks.